# How does the ROC (Region of Convergence) related to a real world application?

Tags: linear-systems, z-transform, dsp-core

In class, we are often given exercises to find the impulse response, output, and Z-transform of a system.  In addition, we are often asked to define the Region of Convergence (ROC) depending on where the poles and zeros are in our system.

I am confused about how to relate the ROC to a real world application.

What does it mean for a system to converge?  How does the ROC relate to causality and stability?

Comment: Please see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Region_of_convergence. If your question still remained unanswered, just let me know.